# No puedo hacer uso de una librería al estar dentro de un If PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un inconveniente al usar una librería para generar QR en PHP este es mi codigo.

```
 <?php
// session_start();
// if ((isset($_GET['sessionIdNew'])) && ($_SESSION['transaccion'] == $_GET['sessionIdNew'])) {

    $textqr = 'hola mundo';
    $sizeqr = 200;  

    include('vendor/autoload.php');
    use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
    $qrCode = new QrCode($textqr);
    $qrCode->setSize($sizeqr);
    $image= $qrCode->writeString(); 
    $imageData = base64_encode($image);
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$imageData.'">';
//}
?>
```

Ahora para que se entienda mejor la situación, cada vez que comento el If la libreria funciona, pero al descomentarla la libreria deja de funcionar.
¿Por qué sucede esto? y ¿existe forma de darle solución ejecutandolo dentro del if?

Comment: deberias guardar el valor que obtienes atravez de las peticiones get en una variable y luego hacer un var_dum(variable) de la variable y ver el resultado puede que alguna variable este vacia por eso no te cumple la condicion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> La palabra reservada use debe ser declarada en el ámbito exterior de
> un fichero (el ámbito global) o dentro de declaraciones de espacios de
> nombres. Esto es así debido a que la importación se realiza durante la
> compilación y no durante la ejecución, por lo que no puede ser
> utilizada en un ámbito de bloque

Al meter el `use` en un `if` lo estás tratando de usar en ámbito de bloque, es por ello que al tenerlo en el `if` el compilador no lo carga correctamente porque considera que estás en ámbito de ejecución. Saca el `use` del `if` y te debería de funcionar.

```
<?php
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
session_start();
if ((isset($_GET['sessionIdNew'])) && ($_SESSION['transaccion'] == $_GET['sessionIdNew'])) {

    $textqr = 'hola mundo';
    $sizeqr = 200;  

    include('vendor/autoload.php');
    
    $qrCode = new QrCode($textqr);
    $qrCode->setSize($sizeqr);
    $image= $qrCode->writeString(); 
    $imageData = base64_encode($image);
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$imageData.'">';
}
?>
```

**Referencia:** [Uso de los espacios de nombres: apodar/importar](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, sin embargo al realizar lo que me dijiste, sacando el use del if ya no da error pero tampoco genera el QR, intente sacar el include tambien pero nada.

Comment: Si no genera el **QR** muy posiblemente sea porque no está entrando por el `if`, asegúrate de que esto esté ocurriendo.

Comment: Me parece una pregunta interesante. El otro día me vino una duda sobre algo parecido, pero con `include/require`. En mi caso, cuando uso `if` para verificar ciertas cosas, no pongo los `include/require` hasta no estar seguro de que **realmente** voy a necesitar ese archivo. A mi juicio es sensato hacerlo así, pero luego, pensando en los `import`  de Java, que se ponen al principio, pensé si no está mal lo que hago con los `include/require` ... ¿Tienes algo sobre el tema?

Comment: @A.Cedano Es que precisamente por eso meti el include dentro del if para no solicitarlo si no lo necesito, pero me aparece error porque no lo reconoce por lo que menciona phpMyGuel, sin embargo al sacar el use tampoco funciona, solo no aparece el error 500.

Comment: @MaikerLeon, según lo que indica esta respuesta no podrás hacerlo así con `use`. Sin embargo, con `include/require` sí es posible. Mi duda es entonces si no es una mala práctica hacer eso con `require/include`. O cuál sería la diferencia entre `use` y `require/include`. Al parecer `use`  funciona como los `import` de Java. En fin, no quiero desviar la atención sobre tu problema...

Comment: @A.Cedano in include/require lo puedes llamar cuando lo necesites, ya se permite su uso en ámbito de ejecición. Tanto es así que puedes usar un include para dar valor a una variable `$foo = include 'return.php';`. **Referencia:** https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php

Comment: @A.Cedano No soy experto en el tema, sin embargo como dice phpMyGuel el include y require se pueden usar en cualquier ambito tanto de ejecución como compilación, mientras que el use no, ademas por lo que tengo entendido como mencione no tengo dominio del tema, el use se utiliza mas que todo para hacer uso de un componente dentro de una instancia.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start()
$sessionNewId = $_GET['sessionIdNew'];
//aca habian parentesis innecesarios, el ! es para verificar que no este vacia 
if ( !isset( $sessionNewId ) && $_SESSION['transaccion'] == $sessionNewId ) {

    $textqr = 'hola mundo';
    $sizeqr = 200;  

    include('vendor/autoload.php');
    use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
    $qrCode = new QrCode($textqr);
    $qrCode->setSize($sizeqr);
    $image= $qrCode->writeString(); 
    $imageData = base64_encode($image);
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$imageData.'">';
}
?>
```

Comment: Pese a que eran innecesarios los paréntesis extras los hago por referencia solamente, su uso o desuso no es lo que ocasiona el error, igualmente muchas gracias.